# React Where to place login page for a one page app with a side menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react web app with a sidemenu. Whenever a user clicks on the link in the sidemenu, they are routed to a page that is rendered at the right side of the sidemenu. My question is, how do I do login for such a usecase seeing as any page I route to renders to the right of the sidemenu. I want the login page to be full screen without the side menu showing. This is what App.js looks like.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./pages/General/components/Navigation";
import SideMenu from "./pages/General/components/SideMenu";
import "../src/css/App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HashRouter>
          <div className="main-wrapper">
            <SideMenu />
            <Navigation />
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is Navigation.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import CalendarPage from "../../Calendar/CalendarPage";
import DoctorsList from "../../Doctors/DoctorsList";
import PatientsList from "../../Patients/PatientsList";
import AdminUsersList from "../../AdminUsers/AdminUsersList";
import SpecialitiesList from "../../Specialities/SpecialitiesList";

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="mainarea">
      <Route exact path="/" component={CalendarPage} />
      <Route exact path="/scheduler" component={CalendarPage} />
      <Route exact path="/doctors" component={DoctorsList} />
      <Route exact path="/patients" component={PatientsList} />
      <Route exact path="/admin-users" component={AdminUsersList} />
      <Route exact path="/specialities" component={SpecialitiesList} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I can figure out in terms of a clean design, is to implement another router in your App.jsx, because you are implementing the routing inside your  component, and you need another one for your login page.

Then, your App.jsx could be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LogIn from "./pages/General/components/Login";
import HomePage from "./pages/General/components/HomePage";
import "../src/css/App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path={'/login'} component={LogIn} />
            <Route path={'/'} component={HomePage} />
            <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then, for your HomePage do the following

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./pages/General/components/Navigation";
import SideMenu from "./pages/General/components/SideMenu";
import "../src/css/App.css";

class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HashRouter>
          <div className="main-wrapper">
            <SideMenu />
            <Navigation />
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it not exactly a solution, but it will give you a basic idea on how to implement this.

The idea is to place the Login component in *app.js*, and conditionally display it if the user is logged in.

You will have to pass a handler function to login component through which you will be able to control *app.js* state.

When login will be sucessfull, u can show the Navigation and Sidemenu component.

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Login from "path/to/login";
class App extends Component {
  state = { isLoggedIn: false };

  loginHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="main-wrapper">
            {isLoggedIn ? (
              <Fragment>
                <SideMenu />
                <Navigation />
              </Fragment>
            ) : (
              <Login loginHandler={this.loginHandler} />
            )}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Also you need write a separate router file, which will contain the main app.
This is used to show the **app** component when navigated to **/**

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './app';

const MainRoute = () => (
    <HashRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </HashRouter>
);
export default MainRoute;
```